# How to force Angular service worker to not use cache when API endpoint parameter (quesrystring/body parameters) changed?

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have a quick question. I have an API endpoint such as /api/getDetails?id=123. The service worker is working and I am getting the information from the cache the second time. My question is what to do when the id change? I want the service worker to allow the API to be called from the server and not use the cache. is it a way to config this? I know that we have performance and freshness, but I am not sure how to setup. I have

```
  {
      "name": "api",
      "urls": ["**/API/**"],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",// OR "freshness"
        "maxSize": 1,
        "maxAge": "1d"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think the sw is handling requests when query parameters have changed? AFAIK a service worker simply looks at the full url and checks if it was fetched before. So when the id changes, the response isn't pulled from the sw, but a new request is sent

Comment: The only thing you need to be aware of is that the entire angular application is cached by the SW, and the visitor won't get the newer versions. To solve this, you need to add/increment the [`version`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/ngsw-config.json#L4) field, and call the [`SwUpdate`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/src/app/app.component.ts#L86-L101)